# How do I compose multiple sourcemaps in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, source-maps

I have a transpiler that takes input source and outputs TypeScript with a valid source map. The TypeScript compiler takes that TypeScript and outputs JavaScript with another source map. Is there a Node.js package or algorithm to compose the source maps so that I can create a new sourcemap that transforms positions in the final `.js` file back to the original source?

```
.civet  ->  .ts   ->   .js
       map1      map2

map3 = map2(map1) essentially
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to iterate through all the mappings in map2 converting their source locations to positions in the original source file by looking up the position in map1.

Assuming the source maps have been parsed into absolute src line/column positions...

Psuedocode:

```coffee
return map2.lines.map (line) ->
  return line.mappings.map (mapping) ->
    [colOffset, fileIndex srcLine, srcColumn] = mapping
    [origLine, origColumn] = map1.lookup(srcLine, srcColumn)
    return [colOffset, fileIndex, origLine, origColumn]
```

There's more nuance for handling the 1 item and 5 item mappings but the general idea is the same.

Then "simply" rewrite the source map with the new mappings (remembering to convert back into relative source offsets and vlq encode.)